# WordR rendering two different outputs for the same input text

Tags: r, ms-word, wordr

Here is the text in my word doc in docx format.
[image: two lines in my input word doc named doc1.docx]

My code is:

```
library(WordR)
renderInlineCode("doc1.docx", "doc2.docx")
```

I am getting this output:
[image: two lines in my output word doc named doc2.docx]

I am getting the 2nd row correct in the output file named doc2.docx, but the first row is not working! What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You have dot instead of space after the "r" in the first row.